# Equality of Scala case class does not work in junit assertEquals when it contains an inner Array

Tags: scala, junit, equals, equality, case-class

I have in scala a 
`case class foo(a: Array[String], b: Map[String,Any])`
I am trying to run unit tests for this but the `assertEquals` while storing the foo elements(actual & expected) in a Arrays.
So the last line is using `assertEquals(expected.deep, actual.deep)`.

The map b is showing correctly, but the assertEquals is trying the match the hashcode of the Array a instead of the content. the error is get is something like this:
`Array(foo([Ljava.lang.string@235543a70,Map("bar" -> "bar")))`

The overall code looks like

```
  case class Foo(a: Array[String], b: Map[String, Any])

  val foo = Foo(Array("1"), Map("ss" -> 1))
  val foo2 = Foo(Array("1"), Map("ss" -> 1))

  org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Array(foo).deep, Array(foo2).deep)
```

How do you suggest making this work?

Comment: Java arrays do not properly implement equality checks. Use a `Seq` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case classes in scala come with their own `hashCode` and `equals` methods that should not be overridden. This implementation checks equality of the content. But it relies on "content" based  `hashCode` and `equals` implementations of types used within the case class.

Unfortunately, this is not the case for `Arrays`, which means that Arrays cannot be checked by content with default `equals` method.

The easiest solution is to use data collections that check equality based on the content, like `Seq`.

```
  case class Foo(a: Seq[String], b: Map[String, Any])

  val foo = Foo(Seq("1"), Map("ss" -> 1))
  val foo2 = Foo(Seq("1"), Map("ss" -> 1))

  org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(foo, foo2)
```

Calling `deep` won't help you in this case as it scans and converts nested `Array` only.

```
  println(Array(foo, Array("should be converted and printed")))
  println(Array(foo, Array("should be converted and printed")).deep)
```

produces

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@188715b5
Array(Foo([Ljava.lang.String;@6eda5c9,Map(ss -> 1)), Array(should be converted and printed))
```